# How do I copy from the search results of the chrome developer tools?

Tags: html, google-chrome, developer-tools

The imgur link has a screen shot of what I am trying to copy so that I don't have to type each value one by one. I've only been able to find how to copy the html from the elements tab but not the list of results when I search from the html in the element.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZQTw.png

Answer (score 0):

After some asking around I'll just answer my own question here in case anyone else has the same one.

All I did was type: $("li.lvprice>span:contains('.00')").text()
into the console and it gave me a nice list I could copy.